# R histogram - define ranges?

Tags: r, histogram

I have a list of customers and then the total amount they have spent. I want to do a histogram of this, but I only want to do for general ranges and not each dollar amount.

Something like 0-500, 501-1000, 1001 - 1500 and so on. is it possible to define these and have the histogram automatically group these together?

Comment: See the `?hist` help page, and specifically the `breaks=` parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

```
hist(x, breaks = c(0, 500, 1000, 1500))
```

should do it.  See `?hist`.